# I want to share a specific activity (Android)

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in which I want to share a specific activity. I've done this previously to share the app through Google Play; but in this case I want to share and when you send the link this directly, open the screen from which you shared; and if you do not have the app installed, take you to the Google Play page. Can someone help me please?
My Code:

MANIFEST:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FichaLibro"
    android:label="@string/strTitleActivityFichaLibro"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />

            </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

JAVA (FichaLibro.java):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha_libro);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        idLibro = intent.getStringExtra("idLibro");
        usuario = (Usuario) intent.getSerializableExtra("usuario");

        altaElementos();


        Intent intentUri = getIntent();
        String action = intentUri.getAction();
        String type = intentUri.getType();
        Uri data = intentUri.getData();
        Uri data2 = (Uri)intentUri.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);


        Log.v("ACTION", action+"");
        Log.v("TYPE", type+"");
        Log.v("URI", data+"");
        Log.v("URI2", data2+"");
```

ALL LOG RETURN NULL. WHY?????

if I create an app with a single activity (MainActivity) and included in the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android: name = "android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android: name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android: name = "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android: scheme = "http"
          android: host = "www.example.com"
          android: Pathprefix = "/ gizmos" />

</ intent-filter>
```

It is supposed to get the value of action, and category data, right?

```
Intent intentUri = getIntent();
String action = intentUri.getAction();
String type = intentUri.getType();
Uri data = intentUri.getData();
Uri data2 = (Uri)intentUri.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

or should I do something else ??

THANKS!!

Comment: What you ask for is called deep linking i think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it a little bit clearer for people who will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Nanoc and bfontaine!!

Answer (score 0):

It's just my guess.
Maybe a link like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=`yourPageckageName`/activtyC

// `<intent-filter>`

// `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

```
// `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

     // `</intent-filter>`
```

Maybe should remove code upon.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="httpa" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

in Activity :

```
 onCreate(){
//read extra
//skip to activityC
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is for share the APP, but no a specific activity. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I do just that, or so I think

Comment: The link is useless .Because browser or app often prevent link from skip itself.

Comment: I dont understand you tiny sunlight, can you explain me with more detail? Thank you!!

Comment: How did you start you activity?  click a link? if a link .what's the link? maybe remove android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" .

Comment: i cant click a http link to start Activity.it's dealed by browser itself.

Comment: In the previous activity i have a list of books, and when i press any send id of book to the activiy "FichaLibro", where i show his information. The i want share a concrete book, for open directly. Sorry but my english is... shit! xD

Comment: ActivityA  List = a,b,c ,Click a =>Activity B ,share a link =>Click link=>ActivityB.